# Gulp - remove local plugin

Tags: gulp

I installed local gulp plugin and realize that I don't need it. How to remove it, is there a command something like `npm remove gulp-sass` for example ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Easy just run `npm uninstall <package-name> --save`. Head over to this link https://docs.npmjs.com/